# How to read this name "番藤茶太郎"?

Tags: kanji, names

Can anyone help me how to read his name and nickname?

name: 番藤茶太郎

nickname: 番茶

Checking with AI seems to give "Fujito Chataro" as name but also "Bandou Chataro" and "Bancha" as his nickname,

Thanks

Comment: Is this from novel [「クラス転移したけど性格がクズ過ぎて追放されました。好きにしろと言われたので固有スキル【穴】で地下に帝国を作ります」](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/16817330662598708319)? That site supports comments, so you can ask author for reading (読み方) of that name.

Comment: I see, never knew you could do that there. Thanks

Comment: Don't trust AI. It will make something up and sound completely confident in it, then if you correct it it will just go along with it even if it was right. It's incapable of knowing if it's right or wrong, it just puts words together according to their frequency in the database.

Comment: Here's a website collecting Japanese family names and their typical readings, origin, statistics etc. ( https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=%E7%95%AA%E8%97%A4 ) Of course, names in fiction often ignore this, but sometimes it helps.

Comment: @Sorakaranko I also have recommendation that you ask author of this novel to add *furigana* to proper names. I have not checked what syntax is used there, but kakuyomu.jp site certainly supports *furigana*, as seen in some other novels written by other authors (e.g. [this novel](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354054881165840) in [here](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/1177354054881165840/episodes/1177354054881165876)).

Comment: @Arfrever As I said in the comment, practically, there is no room for confusion even if there is no furigana. While ばんとう could theoretically be a possible reading, no one would read it that way without furigana.

Comment: @naruto I think that I am not so certain of lack of confusion due to the fact that official *on'yomi* of 藤 in [*jōyō kanji* (常用漢字) list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jōyō_kanji) is とう, not どう...

Answer (score 3):

Practically speaking, this kanji only has one reading, namely "ばんどう ちゃたろう" (or *Bandō Chatarō* in Hepburn romanization). In theory, the [author could assign a tricky reading](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18344/5010) to this kanji, but in such cases, there should be furigana attached to the kanji when this name first appears in the work. Perhaps it was named in such a way that the initial part of the name, 番茶, also happens to be [another word](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%95%AA%E8%8C%B6).

"Fujito" is plain wrong. Current AI systems, including ChatGPT, struggle with guessing the readings of kanji. Large language models like GPT learn from text available on the Internet, but most Japanese text doesn't come with furigana, making it challenging for these models to learn to guess word pronunciations reasonably.

Comment: Another possible reading of 番藤 would be ばんとう (*Bantō*). ENAMDICT/JMnedict lists some surnames with どう and とう reading of 藤, and both can happen after ん of previous kanji.

Comment: Anyway, comments section of [first chapter](https://kakuyomu.jp/works/16817330662598708319/episodes/16817330662598733741) now has official answer from author of novel: "フルネームは「バンドウ　チャタロウ」、ニックネームは「バンチャ」です！"

Comment: As for とう vs どう， I agree with naruto that ばんどう is the only preferred choice of reading (ばんとう is possible, but it would feel atypical, and isn't one's first guess). That's probably because 安藤, 近藤, 遠藤 are all -どう (typically), and there's also 板東 bando.